# How to set optional parameter to default without passing it?

Tags: php

How can i skip first argument without giving any value in function call,so that first argument can take default value NULL?

```
function test($a = NULL, $b = true){
  if( $a == NULL){
     if($b == true){
       echo 'a = NULL, b = true';
     }
     else{
       echo ' a = NULL, b = false';
     }
  }
  else{
    if($b == true){
      echo 'a != NULL, b = true';
    }
  else{
      echo ' a!=NULL, b = false';
      }
  }
}

test();        //ok
test(NULL);    //ok
test(5);       //ok
test(5,false)  //ok
test(,false);  // How to skip first argument without passing any value? ->PARSE error

// i don' want to use default value for first argument, although test(NULL,false)
// or test('',false) will work but can i skip first argument somehow? 
// i want to pass only second argument, so that first arg will be default set by
// function
```

Comment: The requirement you have will require a change in PHP standards :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot just skip an argument in PHP.

You may wish to consider the Perl trick and use an associated array. Use `array_merge` to merge the parameters with the defaults.

e.g.

```
function Test($parameters = null)
{
   $defaults = array('color' => 'red', 'otherparm' => 5);
   if ($parameters == null)
   {
      $parameters = $defaults;
   }
   else
   {
      $parameters = array_merge($defaults, $parameters);
   }
 }
```

Then call the function like this

```
Test(array('otherparm' => 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the arguments, or you can pass the arguments as an array, for exmaple:

```
test($options);
```

Comment: that i don't want to do, i want to set only second arg

Answer (score 0):

Redifine your function as

```
    function test($b = true,$a = NULL){
 //logic here
}
```

And you can call it like test(5); avoiding second parameter.

Comment: that cool for 2 arg but if i want to skip 3rd arg out of 5 optional args?

Comment: then you must pass default value either NULL or 0 or anything else.

Answer (score -2):

YOu have to use the format defined my the PHP function standards

```
test("",false);
```

The requirement you have works with jquery libraries...for arguments passing in its functions.
But NOT in PHP

Comment: What the actual @#$ ? This answer makes definitely no sense!